# jBCrypt dependency not working

Tags: maven, tomcat, heroku, jbcrypt

I am using heroku embedded tomcat for my web application.

In my user registration page, I have function :

```
private static String hashPwd(String pwd) {
    return BCrypt.hashpw(pwd, BCrypt.gensalt());
}
```

I added this dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
    <version>0.3m</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to *git push* my changes, I get an error:

```
cannot find symbol : variable BCrypt
```

at my function call. What am I missing?

My import looks like this:

```
import org.mindrot.*;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently I had to import :

```
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.*
```

instead of

```
import org.mindrot.*
```

Comment: I am trying to do this very thing, however I am getting a "ClassDefNotFound" exception.